# Angular 2 QuickStart npm start error

Tags: angular, npm

I followed exact the same as the start guide that created by angular team. But when I run 'npm start' command. It showed an error - "[0] /c: /c: is a directory
[1] npm run lite exited with code 126". I tried to uninstall node_modules and reinstall again, still the same thing again.
Below is npm-debug.log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.3
3 info using node@v6.6.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~prestart: angular-quickstart@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
7 info lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: angular-quickstart@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\users\j.zeng\desktop\angular-quickstart\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\j.zeng\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\j.zeng\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Toshiba\Bluetooth Toshiba Stack\sys;C:\Program Files (x86)\Toshiba\Bluetooth Toshiba Stack\sys\x64;C:\Program Files\Symantec.cloud\PlatformAgent;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\android-sdk-windows;C:\android-sdk-windows\tools;C:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin;C:\ant\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Ruby22-x64\bin;C:\Users\j.zeng\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
10 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: CWD: C:\users\j.zeng\desktop\angular-quickstart
11 silly lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" ' ]
12 silly lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" `
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:242:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid angular-quickstart@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd C:\users\j.zeng\desktop\angular-quickstart
17 error Windows_NT 10.0.10586
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
19 error node v6.6.0
20 error npm  v3.10.3
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" `
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" '.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite"
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs angular-quickstart
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Package.json file

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.0.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.0.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3",
    "typings":"^1.4.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your package.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set environment variable in Windows:

```
SHELL_EXECUTE_FLAG=-c
```

Or use **cmd.exe**

Concurrently 3.0.0 has a problem with shell detection

References:

https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/concurrently/issues/60

https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/spawn-default-shell/issues/1

Answer (score 0):

Open command prompt screen by "Run as administrator" and try again, or try my simply package to see what happen; https://github.com/Longfld/ng2QuickStartForBeginning